# Is there a specific name for Sheet music that uses numbers (二胡 Èrhú Sheet Music)?

Tags: notation, tablature, erhu

I am searching for a software program (preferably opensource but not necessarily) that can create sheet music. However since I am a beginner at my instrument I still use a simplified notation. I play an ErHu and if you look at this image you will see what the sheet music generally looks like for beginners.

**What type of sheet music is this, does it have a particular name that I can use to search for this type of notation specifically?**  [image: ErHu Sheet Music Example]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ugh, don't you hate when you find the answer to your question right after asking it.

1. numeric notation
2. numerical notation system
3. Also known as Ziffersystem, meaning “number system.”

Sources

http://bennyt85erhu.wordpress.com/jianpu/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jianpu

Answer (score 5):

this is called Jianpu which is the numbered musical notation of most Chinese music

Comment: Ya this is known as Jianpu, or numbered / solfege notation. If you’re looking for the Chinese character it’s 簡譜. Most Chinese instrumental (apart from major Chinese orchestras, they use staff notations), uses this, so does the a large part of Chinese music industry, even in pop music.

Answer (score 2):

It is a form of what is called **tablature** (or *tabulature*, or *tabs* for short). The erhu is a one-string instrument, so the numbers indicate the fingering position for each note on the lone string.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tablature