# What does this weird notation mean (looks like "#.1")?

Tags: guitar, notation

I play guitar using the following scale, which I think is C major. (I don't know the name, but I follow the number on the music note, and it works.)

[image: scale]

I came across the following note:

[image: #.1]

As you can see, this is not a normal .1. It has a # sign beside it. How can I play this on my guitar?

(I am a guitar beginner, with no musical knowledge, so a more detailed answer would be appreciated.)

Comment: [Related question](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/4914/is-there-a-specific-name-for-sheet-music-that-uses-numbers-erhu-sheet-music)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This notation is not common in English material, but it appears that the numbers correspond to the notes of C major scale. 1=C 2=D etc.

The middle octave has no dots. A dot below means it's an octave below, a dot above means it's an octave higher.

So #.1 is probably C# which is one fret higher than the higher C. That's fret 2 on the B string.

This does leave me wondering what the 0 represents. A rest, maybe?

Comment: An 0 in tabs usually stands for an open string.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this notation, but I would assume if you wanted a 2 you'd write a 2 – so perhaps this is a 1, but bent? (I.e. the string is pulled sideways to make the note sharper.)